# How to add buttons and labels in first section of tableview and second section contains only labels

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

```
sections = [
        Section.init(name: "SelectFromOptions", items:  dealnameArray),
        Section(name: "merchant Details", items:merchantdetailsArray),
        Section(name: "How to use deals", items: ["iPhone 6s", "iPhone 6", "iPhone SE", "Accessories"]),
        Section(name: "things to remember", items: ["exchange for cash not allowed"]),
        Section(name: "Cancelation policy", items: ["Once bought cannot exchange"]),
        Section(name: "what you get", items: ["Capacity buliding courses"])
    ]


 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return sections[section].items.count
}

// 
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as UITableViewCell? ?? UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

    cell.textLabel?.text = sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].items[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].collapsed! ? 0 : 44.0
}
```

I want to add different labels and buttons in each section ,is it possible? ,By using bpove code all cells contains only labels,i want to add more labels and buttons in my firt section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom cell. Create a new file called `CustomCell.swift`. Use the following snippet in this file

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!
}
```

Now go to storyboard and add a new prototype cell in your tableview. Select the newly created cell and set it's class to `CustomCell` in the identity inspector (third option - top right).

Set this cell's identifier to *customCell* in attributes inspector (fourth option - top right).

Add a button and a label to this newly created cell and hook up the outlets through connections inspector (last option - top right).

Go back to your code and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, copy the following snippet

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
        //Here you can access the button and the label as cell's property using
        //cell.btn &
        //cell.lbl
        return cell
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

    cell.textLabel?.text = sections[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).section].items[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is simple. Just use two dynamic cells, one containing only labels and another containing buttons and label(or whatever as you required). And use one cell for 1st section and another for second section. That's it.

Comment: Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

you can try that type code..

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var rowCount = 0
        if section == 0 {
            rowCount = Data1.count
        }
        if section == 1 {
            rowCount = Data2.count
        }
        return rowCount
    }



 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
if indexpath.section == 0
{      
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let ip = indexPath
        cell.textLabel?.text = Data1[ip.row] as String
        return cell
    }
else if indexpath.section == 1
{      
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let ip = indexPath
        cell.textLabel?.text = Data1[ip.row] as String
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch indexPath.section {
    case 0:
        //add buttons and labels here
        //prase data
        break
    case 1:
        //add only labels here
        //parse data
        break
    default:
        break
    }
```

or you can do with **if else** as well

```
  if indexpath.section = 0 {
     // create button and label here
     } else {
     // create label here
     }
```

You need to write this snippet in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**